# Find a string in the entire table (all fields, all columns, all rows) in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a module (table) in my Django app with 24 fields (columns), and I want to search a string in it. I want to see a list that show me which one of the rows has this string in its fields.

Please have a look at this example:

```
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| id  | name | year | country | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 | ... | attribute20 | 
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 1   | Tie  | 1993 | USA     | Bond       | Busy       | Busy       | ... | Free        |
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 2   | Ness | 1980 | Germany | Free       | Busy       | Both       | ... | Busy        |
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 3   | Both | 1992 | Sweden  | Free       | Free       | Free       | ... | Busy        |
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| ... | ...  | ...  | ...     | ...        | ...        | ...        | ... | ...         |
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 24  | Lex  | 2001 | Russia  | Busy       | Free       | Free       | ... | Both        |
+-----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

What I am looking to get (by using filters, etc.) is something like this: (When I filter the records base on the word "Both" in the entire table and all of the records. Each row that contains "Both" is in the result below)

```
+----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| id | name | year | country | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 | ... | attribute20 |
+----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 1  | Ness | 1980 | Germany | Free       | Busy       | Both       | ... | Busy        |
+----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 2  | Both | 1992 | Sweden  | Free       | Free       | Free       | ... | Busy        |
+----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| 3  | Lex  | 2001 | Russia  | Busy       | Free       | Free       | ... | Both        |
+----+------+------+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

You can see that the string ("Both") appears in different rows in different columns. (one "Both" is under the column "attribute3", the other "Both" is under column "Name", and the last "Both" is under column "attribute20".

How you get this result in Django by queryset?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have modeled the above table as a Django model named `Person`

```
from django.db.models import Q

query_text = "your search string"
Person.objects.filter(
    Q(name__contains=query_text) |
    Q(year__contains=query_text) |
    Q(attribute1__contains=query_text)
and so on for all your attributes
)
```

The above code will do a case sensitie search. if instead you want it to be case insenssitive search, use `name__icontains` instead of say `name__contains` in the above code.

As suggested by @rchurch4 in comment and based on this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49239720/2348704), here's how one could search the entire table with fewer lines of code:

```
from functools import reduce
from operators import or_
all_fields = Person._meta.get_fields()
search_fields = [i.name for i in all_fields]
q = reduce(or_, [Q(**{'{}__contains'.format(f): search_text}) for f in search_fields], Q())
Person.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: If you want to search literally all of the fields in `Person`, you can get all of the fields using `model._meta` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

Comment: it will save you a lot of lines of code when you want to iterate through a search

Comment: I was wondering how one would write a dynamic filter query after one has access to all fields as a tuple using `model._meta.get_fields()`. Do you have an example ?

Comment: @rchurch4, nvm figured it out and added the code in the reply